# Add multiple textures in xna for windows phone 8 without custom shaders

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I'm building a game using xna and I've created a terrain using VertexElementNormalTexture. I understand I can add position, the normal and texture coordinates to the vertex element but is there anyway to add which texture I want to use. I'm testing it on my Lumia phone so it's being built without the use of custom shaders because they're unsupported by the phone making most of the tutorials on the web out of date. I believe the basiceffects only support one texture per effect so if I make a number of effects how do I get the vertex to know which effect to use? the grasseffect, watereffect, etc.
The code I've got so far is below.
Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors;

namespace WindowsPhoneGame2
{

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    #region // Variables

    public struct VertexPositionColorNormal
    {
        public Vector3 Position;
        public Color Color;
        public Vector3 Normal;

        public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
        (
            new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3 + 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0)
        );
    }

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    RasterizerState rasterizerState;

    // terrain
    BasicEffect grassEffect;
    Texture2D grassTexture;
    BasicEffect waterEffect;
    Texture2D waterTexture;

    VertexDeclaration vertexDeclaration;
    VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices;
    short[] indices;
    VertexBuffer myVertexBuffer;
    IndexBuffer myIndexBuffer;

    private float[,] heightData;
    private int terrainWidth;
    private int terrainLength;
    int nScale = 16;
    Vector3 terrainPosition;
    Texture2D heightMap;

    Matrix viewMatrix;
    Matrix projectionMatrix;
    Matrix worldMatrix;

    // aircraft model
    private Model aircraftModel;
    private Vector3 aircraftPosition;
    Matrix aircraftMatrix;

    // shell model
    private Model shellModel;
    private Vector3 bulletPosition;
    Matrix bulletMatrix;
    bool blBulletFiring;
    private Vector3 torpedoPosition;
    Matrix torpedoMatrix;
    bool blTorpedoFiring;
    float nTorpedoScale;

    // display
    private SpriteFont font;
    float nHeightData;
    int nBullets = 0;
    int nTorpedoes = 0;

    // tilt gesture
    private float rollAngle;
    private float pitchAngle;
    private float yawAngle;
    Accelerometer accelerometer;
    private const int _num = 5;
    private double[] _y = new double[_num];
    private int _index = 0;

    private const int _num2 = 5;
    private double[] _y2 = new double[_num2];
    private int _index2 = 0;

    Texture2D explosionTexture;
    List<ParticleData> particleList = new List<ParticleData>();
    public struct ParticleData
    {
        public float BirthTime;
        public float MaxAge;
        public Vector2 OrginalPosition;
        public Vector2 Accelaration;
        public Vector2 Direction;
        public Vector2 Position;
        public float Scaling;
        public Color ModColor;
    }
    Random random = new Random();

    #endregion



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap | GestureType.Hold;

        loadTextures();
        loadAccelerometer();

        loadCamera();

        loadEffect();
        loadTerrain();
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    private void loadTextures()
    {
        aircraftModel = Content.Load<Model>("Ship");
        shellModel = Content.Load<Model>("Shell");
        explosionTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("explosion");

        heightMap = Content.Load<Texture2D>("heightmap");
        grassTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Grass");
        waterTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Water");

        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("DisplayText");
    }

    private void loadAccelerometer()
    {
        rollAngle = 0;

        if (accelerometer == null)
        {
            accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
            accelerometer.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            accelerometer.CurrentValueChanged += new EventHandler<SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading>>(accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged);
        }

        accelerometer.Start();
    }

    private void loadCamera()
    {
        aircraftPosition = new Vector3(heightMap.Width * nScale * 2 / 2, 0, 400);
        projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 10.0f, 8000.0f);
        worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
        terrainPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    private void loadEffect()
    {
        //grass effect
        grassEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
        //grassEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        grassEffect.LightingEnabled = true; // Turn on the lighting subsystem.
        grassEffect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        grassEffect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(0, 5, -10);
        grassEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
        grassEffect.Texture = grassTexture;

        //water effect
        waterEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
        waterEffect.LightingEnabled = true; // Turn on the lighting subsystem.
        waterEffect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        waterEffect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(0, 5, -10);
        waterEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
        waterEffect.Texture = waterTexture;

    }
    private void loadTerrain()
    {
        LoadHeightData();
        SetUpVertices();
        SetUpIndices();
        CalculateNormals();
        CopyToBuffers();
    }

    private void LoadHeightData()
    {
        terrainWidth = heightMap.Width;
        terrainLength = heightMap.Height;

        Color[] heightMapColors = new Color[terrainWidth * terrainLength];
        heightMap.GetData(heightMapColors);

        heightData = new float[terrainWidth, terrainLength];
        for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength; y++)
                heightData[x, y] = heightMapColors[x + y * terrainWidth].R / 5.0f;
    }
    private void SetUpVertices()
    {
        vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[terrainWidth * terrainLength];
        for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength; y++)
            {
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x * nScale * 2, y * nScale, heightData[x, y] * nScale) + terrainPosition;
            }
        }
    }
    private void SetUpIndices()
    {
        indices = new short[(terrainWidth - 1) * (terrainLength - 1) * 6];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth - 1; x++)
            {
                short lowerLeft = (short)(x + y * terrainWidth);
                short lowerRight = (short)((x + 1) + y * terrainWidth);
                short topLeft = (short)(x + (y + 1) * terrainWidth);
                short topRight = (short)((x + 1) + (y + 1) * terrainWidth);

                indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                indices[counter++] = lowerLeft;

                indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = topRight;
                indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
            }
        }
    }
    private void CalculateNormals()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            vertices[i].Normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            int index1 = indices[i * 3];
            int index2 = indices[i * 3 + 1];
            int index3 = indices[i * 3 + 2];

            Vector3 side1 = vertices[index1].Position - vertices[index3].Position;
            Vector3 side2 = vertices[index1].Position - vertices[index2].Position;
            Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);

            vertices[index1].Normal += normal;
            vertices[index2].Normal += normal;
            vertices[index3].Normal += normal;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            vertices[i].Normal.Normalize();
    }
    private void CopyToBuffers()
    {
        myVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphics.GraphicsDevice, VertexPositionNormalTexture.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        myVertexBuffer.SetData(vertices);

        myIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(graphics.GraphicsDevice, typeof(short), indices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        myIndexBuffer.SetData(indices);
    }

















    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // Adjust camera position
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(aircraftPosition.X, aircraftPosition.Y - 10, aircraftPosition.Z + 5), new Vector3(aircraftPosition.X, aircraftPosition.Y + 5, aircraftPosition.Z ), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

        // Adjust aircraft position
        aircraftMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(rollAngle) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitchAngle) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(yawAngle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(aircraftPosition);
        aircraftPosition.Y += 10.0f;

        // Check against height data for collision
        int x = (int)aircraftPosition.X / (nScale * 2);
        int y = ((int)aircraftPosition.Y - (int)terrainPosition.Y) / nScale;
        if(y < 128) nHeightData = heightData[(int)x, (int)y];
        if (nHeightData > aircraftPosition.Z / nScale)
        {
            aircraftPosition = new Vector3(terrainWidth * nScale * 2 / 2, 0, 400);
            terrainPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }

        // edit weapons fire positions
        if (blBulletFiring)
        {
            bulletPosition.Y += 20;
            fireBullet();

        }
        if (blTorpedoFiring)
        {
            if (torpedoPosition.Z > 5)
            {
                torpedoPosition.Z -= 6;
                torpedoPosition.Y += 10;
                nTorpedoScale = 0.8f;
            }
            else
            {
                torpedoPosition.Y += 16;
                nTorpedoScale = 1.5f;
            }

            fireTorpedo();
        }

        // detect any gestures
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            switch (gs.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.Tap:
                    blBulletFiring = true;
                    bulletPosition = new Vector3(aircraftPosition.X - 0.05f, aircraftPosition.Y, aircraftPosition.Z);
                    AddExplosion(new Vector2(gs.Position.X, gs.Position.Y), 12, 80.0f, 1500.0f, gameTime);
                    // AddExplosion(new Vector2(aircraftPosition.X * -1, aircraftPosition.Y * -1), 12, 80.0f, 1500.0f, gameTime);
                    break;

                case GestureType.Hold:
                    blTorpedoFiring = true;
                    torpedoPosition = new Vector3(aircraftPosition.X, aircraftPosition.Y, aircraftPosition.Z);
                    break;
            }
        }


        if (particleList.Count > 0)
            UpdateParticles(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    private void UpdateParticles(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float now = (float)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        for (int i = particleList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ParticleData particle = particleList[i];
            float timeAlive = now - particle.BirthTime;

            if (timeAlive > particle.MaxAge)
            {
                particleList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                float relAge = timeAlive / particle.MaxAge;
                particle.Position = 0.5f * particle.Accelaration * relAge * relAge + particle.Direction * relAge + particle.OrginalPosition;

                float invAge = 1.0f - relAge;
                particle.ModColor = new Color(new Vector4(invAge, invAge, invAge, invAge));

                Vector2 positionFromCenter = particle.Position - particle.OrginalPosition;
                float distance = positionFromCenter.Length();
                particle.Scaling = (50.0f + distance) / 200.0f;

                particleList[i] = particle;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddExplosion(Vector2 explosionPos, int numberOfParticles, float size, float maxAge, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++)
            AddExplosionParticle(explosionPos, size, maxAge, gameTime);
    }

    private void AddExplosionParticle(Vector2 explosionPos, float explosionSize, float maxAge, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ParticleData particle = new ParticleData();

        particle.OrginalPosition = explosionPos;
        particle.Position = particle.OrginalPosition;

        particle.BirthTime = (float)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        particle.MaxAge = maxAge;
        particle.Scaling = 0.25f;
        particle.ModColor = Color.White;

        float particleDistance = (float)random.NextDouble() * explosionSize;
        Vector2 displacement = new Vector2(particleDistance, 0);
        float angle = MathHelper.ToRadians(random.Next(360));
        displacement = Vector2.Transform(displacement, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle));

        particle.Direction = displacement * 2.0f;
        particle.Accelaration = -particle.Direction;

        particleList.Add(particle);
    }

    private void fireBullet()
    {
        nBullets++;
        bulletMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.1f) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(90)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(bulletPosition);

        if (bulletPosition.Y > aircraftPosition.Y + 200)
        {
            blBulletFiring = false;
        }
    }

    private void fireTorpedo()
    {
        nTorpedoes++;
        torpedoMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(nTorpedoScale) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(90)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(torpedoPosition);

        if (torpedoPosition.Y > aircraftPosition.Y + 1000)
        {
            blTorpedoFiring = false;
        }
    }

    public void accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
    {
        _y[_index++] = e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y;
        if (_index >= _num) _index = 0;
        double ysum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++)
            ysum += _y[i];

        double x = ysum / _num;

        // Cap it at -0.5 and 0.5
        if (x > 0.1)
        {
            if (rollAngle >= -0.9)
            {
                rollAngle -= 0.05f;
                yawAngle += 0.02f;
            }
            if (aircraftPosition.X >= 5) aircraftPosition.X -= rollAngle * -5;
        }
        else if (x <= -0.1)
        {
            if (rollAngle <= 0.9)
            {
                rollAngle += 0.05f;
                yawAngle -= 0.02f;
            }
            if (aircraftPosition.X <= terrainWidth * nScale * 2 - 6) aircraftPosition.X += rollAngle * 5;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rollAngle > 0.05)
            {
                rollAngle -= 0.05f;
                yawAngle += 0.02f;
            }
            else if (rollAngle < -0.05)
            {
                rollAngle += 0.05f;
                yawAngle -= 0.02f;
            }
            else
            {
                rollAngle = 0;
                yawAngle = 0;
            }
        }

        _y2[_index2++] = e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X;
        if (_index2 >= _num2) _index2 = 0;
        double ysum2 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _num2; i++)
            ysum2 += _y2[i];

        double x2 = ysum2 / _num2;

        // Cap it at -0.5 and 0.5
        if (x2 > -0.4)
        {
            if(pitchAngle >= -0.6) pitchAngle -= 0.025f;
            if (aircraftPosition.Z > 6) aircraftPosition.Z -= pitchAngle * -10;
        }
        else if (x2 <= -0.5)
        {
            if (pitchAngle <= 0.6) pitchAngle += 0.025f;
            if (aircraftPosition.Z <= 500) aircraftPosition.Z += pitchAngle * 10;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pitchAngle > 0.05) pitchAngle -= 0.05f;
            else if (pitchAngle < -0.05) pitchAngle += 0.05f;
            else pitchAngle = 0;
        }
    }















    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.CornflowerBlue, 1.0f, 0);
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

        rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
        rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;

        Vector3 oldPosition = terrainPosition;

        loadTerrain();
        DrawTerrain();
        terrainPosition.Y += nScale * terrainLength - nScale;
        loadTerrain();
        DrawTerrain();
        terrainPosition.Y += nScale * terrainLength - nScale;
        loadTerrain();
        DrawTerrain();

        terrainPosition.Y -= nScale * terrainLength - nScale;
        if (aircraftPosition.Y >= terrainPosition.Y)
        { }
        else
        {
            terrainPosition = oldPosition;
        }

        if (blBulletFiring) DrawBullet(shellModel, bulletMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
        if(blTorpedoFiring) DrawTorpedo(shellModel, torpedoMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);

        DrawAircraft(aircraftModel, aircraftMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);

        DrawDisplay();

        DrawExplosion();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    private void DrawTerrain()
    {
        grassEffect.World = worldMatrix;
        grassEffect.View = viewMatrix;
        grassEffect.Projection = projectionMatrix;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in grassEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            GraphicsDevice.Indices = myIndexBuffer;
            GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(myVertexBuffer);
            GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length, indices, 0, indices.Length / 3);
        }
    }
    private void DrawBullet(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.LightingEnabled = true;
                effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.9f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(0, 1, -1);

                effect.World = world;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
    private void DrawTorpedo(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.LightingEnabled = true;
                effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(0, 1, -1);

                effect.World = world;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
    private void DrawAircraft(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                // effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.LightingEnabled = true; // Turn on the lighting subsystem.
                effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f); 
                effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(0, 5, -10);

                //effect.DirectionalLight0.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0, 1, 0); // with green highlights
                //effect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f); // Add some overall ambient light.
                //effect.EmissiveColor = new Vector3(1, 0, 0); // Sets some strange emmissive lighting.  This just looks weird.

                effect.World = world;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
    private void DrawDisplay()
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Position: " + aircraftPosition.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Ground Height: " + nHeightData.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 25), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Bullet Position: " + nBullets.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 40), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Torpedo Position: " + nTorpedoes.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 55), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
    private void DrawExplosion()
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Additive);
        for (int i = 0; i < particleList.Count; i++)
        {
            ParticleData particle = particleList[i];
            spriteBatch.Draw(explosionTexture, particle.Position, null, particle.ModColor, i, new Vector2(256, 256), particle.Scaling, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a BasicEffect, use a DualTextureEffect. I've never used it before because I don't develop for hone but this is supposed to be a very good tutorial. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/08/04/dualtextureeffect.aspx>

Comment: Thank you Liam, I shall have a look at it.